# Ubuntu 16.04: GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend

Tags: wine, gtk, 16.04

My operating system is `ubuntu 16.04`, but when I run a `ELF 32 bit version` program, after running, the program is hanging all the time as the picture shows. Then I close the window, showing the message :
 `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`

[32_gtk_program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivVNP.png)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins may help?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit, I fixed this by installing the 32 bit version of dconf:
sudo apt-get install dconf-gsettings-backend:i386