# Ubuntu 16.04 GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, glib

i keep getting this error. I am not sure how to get rid of it. I am using NVIDIA drivers 381.22 does that cause this problem?

i tried everything from here: [My dconf/gsettings installation is broken. How can I fix it without Ubuntu reinstall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins)
no luck

Comment: It is likely to be a broken link. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins or https://askubuntu.com/questions/761661/ubuntu-16-04-glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend Similar but your link might be different.

Comment: i got it after installing TK/Mayavi and still not fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get that message when I try to use `gsettings` directly (seems unrelated to Nvidia driver), and it looks like it is caused by anaconda or miniconda installing their own version of `glib`.  For me, `which gsettings` shows gsettings within the conda folder tree.  If I change my commands from, for example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default show-sidebar false
```

to explicitly calling the *system* version of gsettings:

```
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.Evince.Default show-sidebar false
```

they don't give that `using "memory" backend` message, and the setting sticks.

Comment: I ran into the same problem helping someone trying to disable encryption for Vino:

    gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false

Comment: This was the (incredibly difficult to find) answer that did it for me. Intuitive way to check / solve the problem!