# locked to launcher icons disapperead

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, icons

Ubuntu 16.04. After upgrade I restarted and my locked to launcher icons disapperead. Now every time I restart I have a clean launcher with standard icons. If I try to open applications and lock to launcher them, after restart they will disappear. Any help?

Comment: update. It seems all the settings are not recorded. As an example I set "natural scrolling" in All settings -> mouse and touchpad settings. but the settings it is not recorded. :-(. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
The issue origin was because some days ago I installed gnome glib-2.0 for c development purpose. I don't know why only after the update the problem arose.
To discover the problem:
from command line after doing:

```
$ unity-control-center
```

I can see the error:

```
GLib-Gio-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

The problem is that in the search path the installed glib (under `usr/local`) is searched before the library referenced by unity.

To solve the problem I ran `sudo make uninstall` from the directory where I downloaded gnome glib. After reboot every icon and setting was restored automatically.

Eventually it would be possible to change the search path of dynamic libraries defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

See also [My dconf/gsettings installation is broken. How can I fix it without Ubuntu reinstall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins)