# gsettings error: using the memory backed

Tags: 16.04, unity, dconf, gsettings

My laptop has very high resolution and I often want to change the scale factor. Until recently the following command worked just fine

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'eDP1': 16 }"
```

But now I am getting the error

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

I tried all the proposed solutions including the accepted answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins) but none worked. If I open the dconf-editor GUI I can change the scale factor just fine but this is less convenient.  I'm lost as to how to fix this but I would love to be able to change the scale factor via a command instead of a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following command line first:

```
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```