# How can I configure vnc-server remotely via SSH

Tags: vnc

I've tried to follow [How to set up remote desktop sharing through SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304017/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-through-ssh) from command line, after connecting via SSH to the server, but `vino-preferences` seems to work only if I have access to GUI:

```
> vino-preferences
vino-preferences: command not found
```

Also, when I try to configure `xhost` it fails:

```
> export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xhost +
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"
```

I currently have no way to access the machine directly, only via SSH.

How can I configure vino-server in such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to manage the `dconf` settings remotely using `gsettings`, using the `org.gnome.Vino` schema

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption
true

$ DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption 'false'

$ DISPLAY=:0 gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption
false
```

Comment: I was getting _"GLib-GIO-Message: 17:36:40.062: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications."_. I've executed `export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/` (following https://askubuntu.com/questions/888683/gsettings-error-using-the-memory-backed) and it helped.