# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see system settings changes

Tags: gnome, system, settings

I'm having a problem with Ubuntu 16.04. I used it for quite a while and then, after rebooting my PC for some reason the system has set a wallpaper to be a default one (and not the one I've set a long time ago), my usual keyboard shortcuts don't work, terminal looks like default (although I configured a theme for it), language pane is gone and the second language is gone.
And the thing is, I can't change anything. When I try to apply changes, nothing happens. For instance: it tries to change Background, but when I close system settings window, nothing happens and everything remains the same.
What can be broken, if I didn't change/install anything and just rebooted my PC?

Comment: Maybe your $HOME directory isn't available (any more). Try logging in from the console (ctrl-alt-F1); if there is some message like `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`, there is a problem with your filesystem or your user configuration.

Comment: I tried to do that, it's fine. No messages you mentioned are being displayed.
I can add that from time to time there appear some messages like "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error".

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this one!
When I launched gedit using terminal I saw a warning: "GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications."
And then I remembered that recently I updated my GLib for Midnight Commander installation. Searched askubuntu and found this thread: [My dconf/gsettings installation is broken. How can I fix it without Ubuntu reinstall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins)
Top answer did the trick, so consider my problem solved.