# Using the 'memory' GSettings Backend

Tags: gnome, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, gsettings

I have a clean Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 and I get this error :

```
[[ ! ]] GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications
```

I tried reinstalling dconf dconf-tools libdconf1 dconf-gsettings-backend etc...

I also checked similar issues on Stack Overflow and nothing worked so far.

How can I fix it?

Comment: when do you get that message?

Comment: When running screenfetch for example.

Comment: Any more examples? What's the behaviour of the program you run? It looks like just a warning? Anyway, see if this is any help https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins