# Super+L to lock screen not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 then to 17.10, and after this the shortcut to lock the screen <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is not working any more. I have checked the keyboard shortcuts and it's configured correctly. Others shortcuts like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> are working fine.

I have tried to bind the lock action to another set of keys but doesn't work either.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver`?

Comment: Hi @pomsky , thanks for the reply, the output is the following:
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

(process:9669): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: unknown schema extension 'd'

(process:9669): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: unknown schema extension 'd'
'<Super>l'

Comment: Wow! That's a mess. See if this fixes anything: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins **Try at your own risk**.

Comment: Can you include the output of `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`

Comment: I was using LightDM, changing the display manager to gdm3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having this problem though without the gsettings weirdness. There's a bug report open here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1715435

Comment: This should really be a comment on the question, although I see you don't have permissions to comment yet.  Do you mind if I place it into the comments?  I do note in the bug report that using gdm3 rather than lightdm 'fixes' the issue.

Comment: I was using LightDM, changing the display manager to gdm3 solved the problem.

Comment: It works for me. Make sure media-keys plugin is active. `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys active` should return true.