# Keyboard shortcuts stop working after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 17.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and wanted to boot with the unity environment, but when I did, I noticed that the keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for the terminal were not working(only when I boot in unity).

How can I fix that?

Comment: Experiencing this also, I think it's a generalisation of this bug report, so I've left a comment there. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1727842

Comment: I'm having the same problem, don't know any solution yet, but doing this:  `rm -rf ~/.compiz ~/.config ~/.gconf ~/.gnome* ~/.kde` solves the problem temporary for me

Comment: It's working temporary, but it's better than nothing. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AramilRey Deleting `.config/` will also remove config files for non-related applications, this is a very bad advice!

Comment: Oh i didn't notice that, but that's true... okay, i'll just avoid addin' the ~/.config

Comment: Yes, try removing some of those one at a time and eventually you will know where the problem is

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972940/keyboard-shortcuts-stop-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-17-10#comment1565882_972940) by Aramil Rey, removing the following configuration files seemed to fix the problem:

- `~/.compiz`
- `~/.gconf`
- `~/.gnome*`
- `~/.kde`

And in my case it was a permanent solution and not a temporarily one. For example this can be done by:

```
mkdir ~/backupFixSO972940
mv ~/.compiz ~/.gconf ~/.gnome* ~/.kde ~/backupFixSO972940
```

If this does not work, you can also add `~/.config` to the list, but be careful as this folder also contains a lot of application related configuration files, thus I advice to make a backup (mv) instead of deleting (rm) all folders directly like from the original solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably related: [Super+L to lock screen not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967986/superl-to-lock-screen-not-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

The comments on the bug linked there suggest to switch from LightDM to GDM3 until the bug is fixed.

Run `sudo apt-get install gdm`, and then your password when prompted, or run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. (Taken from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html))