# Gsettings wallpaper change error ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, command-line, environment-variables, desktop-background, gsettings

I am trying to change the wallpaper in ubuntu using the following code :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 
file:/home/sourajit/Pictures/Wallpapers/skull.jpg
```

However on executing this nothing happens and I am getting this message :

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings 
will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934641/glib-gio-message-using-the-memory-gsettings-backend-your-settings-will-not-b/46486769) solution but it didn't work.

Further here is the output of :

```
which gsettings

/home/sourajit/anaconda3/bin/gsettings
```

Is this location the cause of this problem or there is some other issue? Kindly help.

Comment: The easiest way to change wallpaper is to open `nautilus` navigate to the directory holding the wallpaper image, right click on the image and select "Set as Wallpaper".

Comment: Actually I tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264960/how-to-use-change-desktop-wallpaper-using-python-in-ubuntu-14-04-with-unity) . The python version didn't work so thought the last answer mentioned might work, but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/sourajit/Pictures/Wallpapers/skull.jpg'
```

Comment: Didn't work!Still I am getting the same message as error.

Comment: Did you copy it as one line and not two lines like its formatted in your question?

Comment: I copied it in one line

Comment: I'm at work now but I'll revisit the problem when I get home in 5 hours.

Comment: @Sourajit Have you read this?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins