# gnome-shell settings not saved

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Using Ubuntu 18.04 and GNOME Shell 3.28.1.

Every time I start my computer, I have to

- enable a certain non-system extension I'd like to use, and
- I have to disable Night Light.

Some system extensions have always been reactivated after a reboot, despite the fact I disabled them. I had to remove them from `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Night Light is always set up with some really strange schedulde. If I correct it, it will be resetted after an undefined amount of time.

**I'm guessing some configuration file is broken or has the wrong access rights. But I can't figure out which one.**

Comment: regarding the "Night Light", Can you check with dconf tool? or command line `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false` https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3jCC.png

Comment: The thing is that Night light might be on depending on the current time. For example right now, the schedule is set from 5:00 to 17:00 (it is 11:40 here). Disabling it keeps it off until I restart.

Comment: have you tried above command? ok just to manipulate can you adjust your night light to "manual" and set only 1minute. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJjRW.png

Comment: Yes I did, but what should I see? It was already off. 

I did what you want, what should I look after now?

Comment: I set it to 12:00-12:01, now at 12:03 it resetted to 6:00-18:00

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color active false`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that my settings are not preserved after a reboot

Comment: Yes. You are rite. When I am trying in my laptop all the settings are saved. In your case something might have overwriting it. Have you ever changed any settings after you installed Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by removing some settings folders and just configuring everything from scratch. I found some valuable information in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/558450/548635

What I finally did is:

```
mv ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/dconf.old
mv ~/.gnome ~/.gnome.old
mv ~/.gconf ~/.gconf.old
```