# 'gsettings' throws error while setting scroll wheel to switch between windows on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, dconf, ubuntu-dock, gsettings, mouse-scroll

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) to 18.04 (GNOME 3).

I am trying to recover some Unity features I enjoy, such as switching between windows with just scrolling the mouse wheel over the app icon on the launcher or Ubuntu dock, making a sort of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> effect, and if there are several windows for a same application (e.g. several .pdf opened at once), it switches between them (sort of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>œ</kbd> effect).

I have been mentioned the

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

command, but it has basically no effect on my computer. I just get

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

which I don't really understand. I was told to install dash-to-dock and to run

```
sudo apt install dconf-gsettings-backend
```

but it did not change anything (to me) either (dconf-gsettings-backend was already installed).

Fyi, I also tried, since it is in the same vein, to run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

I get the same output as above, and it does not seem to do anything either.

---

Additional information:
As suggested, I tried

```
user@xxx : /etc/ld.so.conf.d$ ls
cuda-9-0.conf  fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  i386-linux-gnu.conf  libc.conf  x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf
```

I also tried:

```
$ which gsettings
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/gsettings
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

Comment: I have seen this but since it is quite old I wasn't sure it was relevant. Plus, I don't understand much of what the OP answer, and I don't get similar results, thus I don't know how to apply the fix proposed.
(see edited question) I also run which gsettings, as suggested by 2nd answer, and got
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/gsettings, 
I guess this is an interesting point, but I am not knowledgeable about PATH and comments suggest to not mess with it.

Comment: I obtain 
    `error: 0-5:unknown keyword`
it appears that I have no /org/ repo at the root level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with `gsettings` try using `dconf` command instead. For example, in place of

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

run

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/scroll-action "'cycle-windows'"
```