# How do I set "all windows" by default when left clicking on a application that has more than one window?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I really don't like when I have more than one window on a single application and have to:

*Right click > All windows > choose the one I want.*

I would like to do it on the first *Left click* like in Ubuntu 16.04.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Comment: It worked, but first I have to solve a problem with python anaconda https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

Answer (score 0):

The option that is similar to the default of 16.04 is set using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize-or-overview'
```

Comment: It worked, but first I have to solve a problem with python anaconda https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins