# Ubuntu Dock is showing in all the displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, in my Dell XPS 13. I connected an external monitor and used it as the primary monitor. And initially, the dock was in the external monitor only. Then I went to the *Settings* > *Appearance*. And changes the show on to All displays. I tried turning it back to the external display, but it is not changing.

I tried restarting, and to change the setting, but nothing works. I just want to keep my laptop's built-in monitor clean without the dock.

Comment: @pomsky I tried it, it says ```GLib-GIO-Message: 11:08:43.624: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.```

Comment: That's a separate issue. Your `gsettings`/`dconf` is broken: https://askubuntu.com/q/558446/480481

Comment: yes following this fixed my issue https://askubuntu.com/a/861380/1072998 , thanks for your help @pomsky